# Google Big query python - exception: 503 failed to connect to all addresses

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am using Big query sample code from google documentation to setup connection to Google Big query for example table

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('credentials.json')

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)

gbq_query = """SELECT count(*) as count FROM project.dataset.table"""

query_job = client.query(gbq_query)
results = query_job.result()
result_to_df = results.to_dataframe()
print(result_to_df)
```

which runs correct in case of outside of corporate network, but in corporate network where I want to automate run I'm getting this errors : 503 failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:142.250.185.138:443 (each call different google IPs)

Also there is corporate firewall, but there we have whitelisted google api endpoints which are part of call - oauth2.googleapis.com, bigquery.googleapis.com, iam.googleapis.com

```
[ERROR] RetryError: Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling target function, last exception: 503 failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:142.250.185.138:443: Handshake read failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/envs/google_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google_example/entry_point.py", line 7, in handler
    bigquery_call()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/google_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google_example/gbq/gbq_call.py", line 78, in bigquery_call
    result_to_df = results.to_dataframe()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/google_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py", line 2155, in to_dataframe
    record_batch = self.to_arrow(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/google_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py", line 1825, in to_arrow
    for record_batch in self.to_arrow_iterable(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/google_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py", line 1688, in _to_page_iterable
    yield from result_pages
  File "/opt/conda/envs/google_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py", line 885, in _download_table_bqstorage
    session = bqstorage_client.create_read_session(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/google_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_storage_v1/services/big_query_read/client.py", line 516, in create_read_session
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/google_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 154, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/google_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 283, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/google_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 205, in retry_target
    raise exceptions.RetryError(
```

I'm using this versions of libraries:

```
- google-api-core=2.10.1
- google-api-core-grpc=2.10.1
- google-auth=2.6.0
- google-cloud-bigquery=3.11.4
- google-cloud-bigquery-core=3.11.4
- google-cloud-bigquery-storage=2.11.0
- google-cloud-bigquery-storage-core=2.11.0
- google-cloud-core=2.3.2
- google-crc32c=1.5.0
- google-resumable-media=2.4.0
- googleapis-common-protos=1.56.4
```

any advise?

Thank you in advance